# Error when comparing two date values

Tags: linux, shell

Shell script works fine for other days but not for date 2013-12-08 and 2013-12-09 
Below is code I am trying with-:

```
  dateToLook=`(date +%d-%m-%Y --date='1 days ago')`
dateToLookY=`(date +%Y-%m-%d --date='1 days ago')`
last=`grep "cricket"  /root/live/test.csv | sed 's/"//g'| awk  'BEGIN { FS = "," } ; { print $8 }' | awk  'BEGIN { FS = " " } ; { print $1 }' | grep "$dateToLookY" | head -1`
d=`(date +%Y-%m-%d --date='1 days ago')`
echo $last--$d
if [[ $d -eq $last ]];
then
echo "deepak"
else
echo "condition does not match"
fi
```

when these two variable echoed they gives same value but if compared in "if" condition it returns false and else condition executed.
Below is the file I am trying with test.csv-:

```
"@yahoo.com","123","40","M","i","1.3","2013-11-19","2013-12-08"
"@yahoo.com","123","40","M","i","1.3","2013-11-19","2013-12-08"
```

I had browsed over internet not find out why this is happening the same code works when i modify date in Test.csv with 2013-12-06

Answer (score 1):

```
if [[ $d -eq $last ]];
```

tests for integer equality, you want a string test here, as in

```
if [[ $d = $last ]];
```

It's just a bit surprising that your shell doesn't give you a reasonable error message here, when I try this here in (a rather old) bash, I get

```
[[: 2013-12-08: value too great for base (error token is "08")
```

explanation: [[ sees numbers in a numerical expression and per C convention numbers starting with 0 are interpreted as octal, which explains why 06 and 07 would work, 08 and 09 not.  `[[` also does hexadecimal, see [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html#DBLBRACKETS)

But in this case you wanted string comparison, so this last part of the explanation is actually not really relevant, it just explains the error.

From the [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html):

> [[ ... Returns a status of 0 or 1 depending on the evaluation of the conditional expression expression. Expressions are composed of the primaries described below in Bash Conditional Expressions.

and from the chapter on Conditional Expressions:

```
string1 == string2
string1 = string2

    True if the strings are equal. ‘=’ should be used with the test command
    for POSIX conformance.
```

Comment: i am getting this error  [[: 2013-12-08: value too great for base (error token is "08") and only for value 08 and 09..

Comment: See the explanation I added, I somehow sensed you were going to ask this :)

Comment: Ok i agree but i am new to shell scripting so i might be doing some unknown mistakes...please help to find how could i do this... i want to execute "if" when date fetched matched with date assigned in $d

Comment: Please read my answer again, as you want string equality you need to write `if [[ $d = $last ]];` and ***not*** `if [[ $d -eq $last ]];` which tests for ***numerical*** equality.

Comment: i had just tried with if [[ $d == $last ]] and it works fine ...as i read $d = $last means assigning $last value to $d ...if we see in context of PHP and C.. might be i am wrong but its just a simple doubt

Comment: Both work  (`=` being the traditional `test` aka `[` program compatible form, `==` added by bash's built-in `[[` "test-deluxe" functionality).  In case of doubt there's always the documentation (see my latest edit) and especially on Linux, the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/test)